# Java error in Android studio issue now resolved

Tags: c++

I have the latest version of Java, but Android Studio states that I have an older version, in the Project structure it says the project SDK is "1.8(Java version 1.8.0_52)" (mine is 1.8.0_201). How do I resolve this?

Comment: Android Studio comes with its own Java. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your `Target Compatibility` under `File > Project Structure`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To select your own JDK do the following:

1-Go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location

2-Uncheck "Use embedded JDK"

3-Click on "..." icon and select your JDK location.

[image: setup custom JDK in android studio]

Comment: What is your android studio version?